# different timeAgo in different device with diffrent time

Tags: android, date, time, timezone, timeago

I want to get timeAgo of some data, for example I inserted some data to database about three hours ago, but in different devices with different time zones, I see a different timeAgo.

What should I do? 
 This is my code

```
public static String timeAgo(long millis) {     
    long diff = new Date().getTime() - millis;
    Resources r = G.context.getResources();


    String prefix = r.getString(R.string.time_ago_prefix);
    String suffix = r.getString(R.string.time_ago_suffix);


    double seconds = Math.abs(diff) / 1000;
    double minutes = seconds / 60;
    double hours = minutes / 60;
    double days = hours / 24;
    double years = days / 365;


    String words;


    if (seconds < 45) {
        words = r.getString(R.string.time_ago_seconds, Math.round(seconds));
    } else if (seconds < 90) {
        words = r.getString(R.string.time_ago_minute, 1);
    } else if (minutes < 45) {
        words = r.getString(R.string.time_ago_minutes, Math.round(minutes));
    } else if (minutes < 90) {
        words = r.getString(R.string.time_ago_hour, 1);
    } else if (hours < 24) {
        words = r.getString(R.string.time_ago_hours, Math.round(hours));
    } else if (hours < 42) {
        words = r.getString(R.string.time_ago_day, 1);
    } else if (days < 30) {
        words = r.getString(R.string.time_ago_days, Math.round(days));
    } else if (days < 45) {
        words = r.getString(R.string.time_ago_month, 1);
    } else if (days < 365) {
        words = r.getString(R.string.time_ago_months, Math.round(days / 30));
    } else if (years < 1.5) {
        words = r.getString(R.string.time_ago_year, 1);
    } else {
        words = r.getString(R.string.time_ago_years, Math.round(years));
    }


    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();


    if (prefix != null && prefix.length() > 0) {
        sb.append(prefix).append(" ");
    }


    sb.append(words);


    if (suffix != null && suffix.length() > 0) {
        sb.append(" ").append(suffix);
    }


    return sb.toString().trim();
}
```

Comment: Please give sample input and output so we can see what you mean. (Is it possible that it's just a matter of the clock being wrong?)

Comment: It most likely is due to the differences in time settings or time zones.  The best way to avoid that is to return dates in UTC format and calculate those times based off of UTC since it doesn't vary by time zone.

Comment: for example this is my date ( timeAgo ) in database : 11/2/2011 and in the device date is 11/2/2016 , and current date/time is 11/2/2015 , but in the device show me it's 5 years ago ( it should be 4 years ago , but how ?) sorry about my English again